# Cloudant 429 too many model

Tags: java, spring, maven, cloudant

I'm using the free subscription to cloudant, so I could do only 5 query per second.

I have also 6 models with 6 repos and at the initialization of the repos I call createIndex:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void initRepo() {
        db = dbManager.getDatabase();
        List<Index> indexes = db.listIndices();
        String indexName = String.format("index_%s", getModelClass().getSimpleName());
        if (indexes != null && !indexes.stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals(indexName)).findFirst().isPresent()) {
            Log.debug("Creating index for " + indexName);
            db.createIndex(indexName, indexName, null,
                    getIndexFields() != null ? getIndexFields().toArray(new IndexField[0]) : null);
        }
    }
```

Using `mvn test` or `mvn install` all the 6 initRepo are called so I get 429.

Could I tell spring to wait 5 second before initializing some repos?
Or there are a best practice to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

1) Queue your Cloudant operations and only consume items from the queue at rate less than the rate-limit (say 4 per second)

2) Upgrade your Cloudant service to a more generous plan

3) The java-cloudant library has a option to use a [429ReplayInterceptor](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-http/2.11.0/com/cloudant/http/interceptors/Replay429Interceptor.html). This will retry API calls that get a 429 response with exponential back-off.